# how can I track down the source of "Internal connection fatal error"?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I'm working on a 6-700 line SQL script today. I'm running it from SSMS. Pointing at a SQL 11.0 db. About half the time I run it, I get:

`An error occurred while executing batch. Error message is: Internal connection fatal error.`

Googling for that didn't yield anything worthwhile. What could be causing this error? There aren't any RAISERRORs. It doesn't happen every time but it has happened about 20 times today. How can I track down the actual source of this error?

Comment: Try using sqlcmd and see if you get the same error or not.

Comment: Are you running this in SSMS on your desktop? Where is the server you are running against?

Comment: Yes, it's on my desktop while the SQL box is downstairs.

Comment: Sounds like you have flaky connectivity then. Are you connecting to the SQL Server machine over your home WiFi? Do you have a domain? How are you connecting to the box (TCP/IP, named pipes)? Are you using IP address, server name, FQDN, ...? What do you see in the actual SQL Server error log?

Comment: @AaronBertrand on a domain, wired connection; there's no errors in the SQL logs.

Comment: If there's nothing in the log then the request isn't even making it to SQL Server.